# Code not working with include_once

Tags: php, include

This is my code for image.php

```
<?php 

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); 
include_once 'token.php';

$im = ImageCreateFrompng("certificate.png"); 

$black = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 0); 

$start_x = 35; 
$start_y = 230; 

Imagettftext($im, 20, 0, $start_x, $start_y, $black, 'ambient.ttf', 'name'); 

Imagejpeg($im, '', 100); 

ImageDestroy($im); 

?>
```

It doesn't give any error but is not showing any image in image.php file but when i remove include_once, it works fine. Now including token.php is important because i want to merge text dynamically from facebook and it contains api for facebook. This code was working fine until i changed permissions on the folder which contains those files. I also tried including any random file but it behaves the same way. Any help or suggestion?

P.s: image.php and token.php are in same folder.

here is code for token.php

```
<?php

include_once 'facebook.php';
include_once 'config.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
'cookie' => true,
'domain' => 'XXXX'
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

if (!$session) {

$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 0,
    'req_perms' => 'read_stream,publish_stream',
    'next' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/****'

));

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$url';</script>";

} else

 {

try {
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$me = $facebook->api('/me');


}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
 echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Im assuming include or include_once doesnt make a difference? Also please include the code for token.php. Also, test this script without the header and see what happens. If you generate errors and the header is jpg, it wont come out right. Also, make sure you set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Is it possible you have a php closing tag in token.php and a white space after it? That would send output to browser and break your script.

Comment: i dont think code for token.php is effecting because this code is showing same behavior for every file i'm including

Comment: same output when i removed the header

Answer (score 0):

You do have a echo statement in there. It will break your script since you are outputting an image. Try commenting out the echo.

Also its possible the problem is in facebook.php or config.php since both these files are included by token.php.

Comment: no error comes after setting error_reporting(E_ALL); and there are no breaks

Comment: The situation described by Iznogood probably will not raise an error. Try commenting the echo in token.php

Comment: even commenting out echo is not helping. u guys r not understanding. this is happening by including any random php file with no errors and no echo .

Comment: @Anurag well you are not understanding that you are either missing something obvious or nto telling us everything. It should work. Its perfectly ok to include a file. It works. Something is wrong in your stuff somewhere.

Comment: @Anurag try something for us. Include an empty file. A file with nothing at all or ideally a single php opening tag <?php. If it still breaks something might be wrong with your include paths. Somehow php is not finding your files.

Comment: @Anurag then its obvious something in the file is breaking. The echo for sure should not be there. Alternatively facebook might be redirecting you or something like that.

Comment: Also its possible the problem is in facebook.php or config.php since both these files are included by token.php.